# xarray.DataArray how get single element

Tags: python, arrays, python-xarray

I want to create a three-dimensional table that contains numbers. For two-dimensional data I would just use a csv-file or a pandas.DataFrame, but this appeared to be not so easy to use for three dimensions. I decided to use `xarray`. If you think, there are easier solutions, feel free to tell: I only want to create the array, save it in file and read it out for later use. Each column won't have more than 100 elements.

I create the array (and access it) using

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
da =xr.DataArray(
    np.ones((4,4,4),dtype=int),
    [
        ("x-col", ['a','b','c','d']),
        ('y-col', ['A','B','C','D']),
        ('z-col', [1,2,3,4])
    ]
)
da.loc['a','C',2]=4
da
```

which gives

```py
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 4, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]]])

Coordinates:
    x-col (x-col) <U1   'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
    y-col (y-col) <U1   'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'
    z-col (z-col) int32 1 2 3 4

Attributes: (0)
```

as expected. However if I want to access the number using `da.loc['a','C',2]` I still get

```py
array(4)

Coordinates:
    x-col () <U1   'a'
    y-col () <U1   'C'
    z-col () int32 2

Attributes: (0)
```

Is there a way such that I get the number 4 without the wrapping?

Also, can you propose an elegant method how to store the DataArray to disk so I can use it later?

Comment: for future reference - please ask only one question per post :) you can extract a single-element DataArray to a python scalar with the DataArray's [`da.item()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.item.html) method. And there are a lot of ways to read/write xarray data. As the [xarray docs on reading and writing files](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html) state - netCDF is a good place to start, e.g. with [`ds.to_netcdf(filepath)`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf.html#xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing individual elements in xarray DataArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270121/accessing-individual-elements-in-xarray-dataarray)

Comment: So `da.loc['a','C',2].item()` would be the standard way? I tried it out, it works great.
Thanks also for the link to the 'reading and writing files'-documentation. It works fine.

Comment: yep exactly. glad it helped!